# (python plotly 5.7.0) It doesn't display graph when ther's NO INTERNET, it still required internet to show graphs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using python 3.6.8 and plotly 5.7.0

```
[user1@testsrv1 ~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[user1@testsrv1 ~]$ pip3 freeze | grep -i plotly
plotly==5.7.0
[user1@testsrv1 ~]$ pip3 show plotly
Name: plotly
Version: 5.7.0
Summary: An open-source, interactive data visualization library for Python
Home-page: https://plotly.com/python/
Author: Chris P
Author-email: chris@plot.ly
License: MIT
Location: /home/opc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: tenacity, six
```

I'm expecting the plotly graphs to be displayed in server where there's no internet connection, but it's NOT displaying. As per plotly document, from plotly 4, graphs are Offline only -- https://medium.com/plotly/plotly-py-4-0-is-here-offline-only-express-first-displayable-anywhere-fc444e5659ee!
I'm using below code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
graph1 = px.histogram(dataframe, x='TIME_BUCKET', color='CATEGORY',  title='Category Histogram')
graph2 = px.bar(dataframe, x="CATEGORY", y="COUNT", title="Category wise execution count")
                with open("report.html", 'w') as f:
                    f.write(graph1.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
                    f.write(graph2.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

Now when I open report.html (from VM whare there's No internet connection), it doesn't show any graph.

But when I forcefully use plotly offline like below the html shows graph.

```
plotly.offline.plot(graph1, filename=outhtml_path, auto_open=False)
```

I'm expecting plotly normal functions (not the pyhon.offline.plot) to show the graphs in VMs without any internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. in below code
f.write(graph1.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
f.write(graph2.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
**changed include_plotlyjs='cdn' to include_plotlyjs=True and it solved the problem.**

```
f.write(graph1.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=True))
f.write(graph2.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=True))
```

As per documentation (https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.html),

*include_plotlyjs (bool or string (default True)) –
Specifies how the plotly.js library is included/loaded in the output div string.
If True, a script tag containing the plotly.js source code (~3MB) is included in the output. HTML files generated with this option are fully self-contained and can be used offline.
If ‘cdn’, a script tag that references the plotly.js CDN is included in the output. HTML files generated with this option are about 3MB smaller than those generated with include_plotlyjs=True, but they require an active internet connection in order to load the plotly.js library.*